# How do I show an image made from a pixel map?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Ok, so I tried to edit an image and turn the edited result into a pixel map.
That worked well, but I just don't know how to turn that pixel map into an actual image and show it.

This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = Image.open('sample.jpg')
pixels = img.load()

for i in range(img.size[0]): # for every pixel:
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        if pixels[i,j] == (255, 0, 0):
            pixels[i,j] = (0, 0 ,0)

im2 = Image.fromarray(pixels)
im2.show()
```

Also, I'm getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Haris.Sabotic\Desktop\Image Color Inverter\code.py", line 15, in <module>
    im2 = Image.fromarray(pixels)
  File "C:\Users\Haris.Sabotic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2508, in fromarray
    arr = obj.__array_interface__
AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'
```

Comment: you don't have to convert `pixels` because it change value directly in `img` so you need `img.show()` to see result.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to convert `pixels` back to image because `pixels` changes values in original `img` - so you have to display `img.show()`

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('sample.jpg')
pixels = img.load()

width, height = img.size 
for col in range(width):
    for row in range(height):
        if pixels[col,row] == (255, 0, 0):
            pixels[col,row] = (0, 0 ,0)

img.show()
```

---

**EDIT:** You need `fromarray()` when you convert to numpy array

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img1 = Image.open('sample.jpg')

pixels = np.array(img1)

pixels[np.all(pixels == (255, 0, 0), axis=-1)] = (0,0,0)

img2 = Image.fromarray(pixels)
img2.show()
```

BTW: if you have to get pixel in array then remeber that array uses `[row,col]` instead of `[col,row]`